# How can I reverse the order of a list in CSS, remove the last value, and keep centered?

Tags: css, frontend, reverse, web-frontend

I am putting together a [template for a website][1].

The code in the editor is:

```
<div class="post-meta vcard"><p>
<a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/" rel="tag">France</a>, 
<a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/paris/" rel="tag">Paris</a>, 
<a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/paris/things-to-do/" rel="tag">Things to Do in Paris</a>
</p></div>
```

I would like the output to just be Paris, France.  How would I achieve this with CSS?  Assuming the steps would be reverse order and remove first variable in the list.

Comment: Hi, please include the code you are working with in your question, ideally make a snippet. Thanks

Comment: I just added the code from the editor.  The current output is France, Paris, things to do in Paris.  I'd like it to just output Paris, France.  (these are list of the categories the article is included in)

Comment: Have you tried `display: none` and `flex-direction`? The comas will do some mess here, maybe you can set them in `::after` pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reverse the order of the links and center everything using flexbox
2. Give all text `font-size: 0` - this hides everything
3. Give links to show `font-size: 1rem`
4. Reintroduce comma as a `pseudoelement`.

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

a:not(:last-child) {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

/* reintroduce comma */
a:first-child:before {
  content: ',';
  margin-right: .5ch;
  float: left;
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-meta vcard">
  <p>
    <a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/" rel="tag">France</a>,
    <a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/paris/" rel="tag">Paris</a>,
    <a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/paris/things-to-do/" rel="tag">Things to Do in Paris</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sol!  By chance, any idea on how to keep 1 comma so it reads "Paris, France"?

Comment: Thank you so much!  Works perfect!  I made a slight change to add a space, and was able to slightly reduce the code in the last part.  It centers and adds a space after the comma:                                                      .post-meta a:first-child:before {
    content: ',\00a0';
    white-space: pre;
    color: initial }

Answer (score 1):

Tricky part is use of the comma. You can see the effect hovering over the tags.

I used a flexbox to display the tags and use `row-reverse` on `hover`. Keep in mind that the actual order of the items doesn't change, so when hovering the last child on the screen is actually the first child in the flexbox.

Hope this helps.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tags:hover {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.tags:not(:hover)>span:not(:last-child)::after,
.tags:hover>span:not(:first-child)::after {
  content: ", ";
}

.tags:hover>span:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
  <div class="tags">
    <span>France</span><span>Paris</span><span>Things to do in Paris</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The space character after the comma is not taken into account. Maybe this could be worked around with some `margin-right` or a fixed-width space

Answer (score 1):

I would dare to do this:

```css
p {
  direction: rtl;
  color: transparent;
}

p a {
  display: inline-block;
}

p a:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-meta vcard">
  <p>
    <a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/" rel="tag">France</a>,
    <a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/paris/" rel="tag">Paris</a>,
    <a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/paris/things-to-do/" rel="tag">Things to Do in Paris</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjxZYg).

Comment: I took the liberty to make a snippet from your Codepen. There are a few problems with your solution, like the text is now aligned to the right because of RTL, and also the comma is not showing up (although present)

Comment: @JeremyThille It's the price of simplicity, my friend :). Now he can choose which one to use. Thanks for the editing.

Comment: @jeremythrille, where would I be able to see your version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that this is not the best approach. If you resort to these kind of hacks, your site will be a pain to maintain.

Anyway, here is my approach using `flexbox`. It's similar to other answers but:

1. I don't change the HTML (I assume you can't).
2. I try to make it look **good**, as if you were just HTML (and not a hack).

I just hide the comma behind the parent div, so if you use a different font-size you will need to ajust to that (or just use `em`).

```css
/* Hide the comma */
.post-meta {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-meta p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse; /* Reverse order of elements... */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* ...and move them to the left */
  position: relative;
  left: -3px; /* Move a notch to the left so we can hide the comma */
}

/* Make up for the removed space */
p a:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 3px;
}

/* Hide 'Things to Do' */
p a:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-meta vcard"><p>
<a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/" rel="tag">France</a>, 
<a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/paris/" rel="tag">Paris</a>, 
<a href="http://wordpress-114402-466332.cloudwaysapps.com/france/paris/things-to-do/" rel="tag">Things to Do in Paris</a>
</p></div>
```

Comment: This worked great!  My only issue was centering, but not sure if it is possible.  Currently, it is pushed to the left.  When I change justify-content to "middle", the comma reappears.